# law about ethical hacker using pirated software or gadgets?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, fair-use, ownership, hacking

Is there any law if a ethical hacker is invited to our company and he used pirated software?
Can we take any legal action or its normal in this field?

Comment: It is worth mentioning, using pirated software means any findings (especially if forensics) would not be allowed in court, as expert witnesses etc... must provide evidence that their software is licenced, working correctly, and that they are competent. Furthermore, pirated software can sometimes contain computer malware (viruses), so aside from not working properly, you might end up opening the door wide open to hackers, rather than protecting yourself which is the reason you likely hired an ethical hacker to begin with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take legal action about pirated software if you are the copyright holder. You can surely uninvite someone who needs to be trusted if you have reasons not to trust their integrity, and if they use pirated software that is a good reason not to trust them. You can also inform the copyright holder.

PS. "Ethical hackers" by definition don't use pirated software. They may talk companies into supplying them with software without paying for it, that's different.